# UnboundLocalError at ConnectionError for API call with requests

Tags: python

I am trying to write myself a function to handle my calls to an API, which return a JSON. This is my function at the moment:

```py
import requests

def get_data(url:str, headers:str, timeout_seconds=5) -> str:
    """Return JSON file from API call."""
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout_seconds
            )
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("Http Error:", errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print("Error Connecting:", errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print("Timeout Error:", errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("Unspecified error:", err)
    return response.json()
```

This works fine when the request is successful, but when trying to simulate an error by disconnecting from the internet, I get this error additonally to the Connection Error. Is this something I'm not handling correctly in my function?

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the call to `requests.get()` throws an exception in the line `response = requests.get( url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout_seconds )`
the variable `response` is never assigned.  This is causing the UnboundLocalError when you try to access `response.json()` as `response` has no meaning

Here is one possible solution:

```
import requests

def get_data(url:str, headers:str, timeout_seconds=5) -> str:
    """Return JSON file from API call."""
    response = None
    try:
        response = requests.get(
            url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout_seconds
            )
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("Http Error:", errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print("Error Connecting:", errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print("Timeout Error:", errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("Unspecified error:", err)
    if response is None:
        return None # returning {} or raising an exception are also options.
    return response.json()
```

Depending on how you want the caller to handle this and check for no data, you could return `None`, an empty dict, or raise a custom Exception indicating a failure to retrieve the data.

Comment: I'll add that `""` is another possible empty response.  `response.json()` ultimately calls `json.loads()` which will return a dict when it can, and a str otherwise (at least that's the clearest explanation I can find as all of the docs just say a "JSON object").  My test URL resulted in dict.

Comment: Yeah I was wandering about the type of JSON objects as well. dict seems more realistic than string, I'll check with my jsons. Thank you for your help! Is returning "None" the best way, if I want to "notify" the function in which get_data() is called? I'd use something like `if data == None: break` I guess. Or has raising a custom exception any advantages for this?

Comment: If this function is just something you're using in your own code, its probably more of a personal preference than a 'best' way to use it, and depending on how you're designing the caller.  If you have it return an empty string or empty dict, then you can just do a check of `if data:`, which implicitly does a len() check and will return `False` for an empty dict or str.   Returning None and checking `if data is None:` or `if data is not None:` forces the caller to explicitly handle this response otherwise they might try calling a dict or str method on `None` and raise an `AttributeError`

Comment: Note that the canonical check for None is `is None` or `is not none`.  This is because the identity comparison done by `is` cannot be overridden, but the equality check done by `==` can be overridden by a class; a class could be written that returns `True` for `obj == None` when obj is not actually `None`, and vice versa.   
 Raising a custom exception to wrap all of the possible connection errors into a single exception might make sense if you were developing a full package for other consumers.  The other option is to move the entire try/except block outside the function to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

Return is located out of try-except block, if exception is occurred, then response object is not exists. Place return inside `try` block.

Or you can handle all requests exceptions like this:

```
import requests
from typing import Optional


def get_data(url: str, headers: str, timeout_seconds: int = 5) -> Optional[str]:
    """Return JSON file from API call."""
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout_seconds)
        return response.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("Error:", e)
```

Note, that return value of `get_data` is set to `Optional` in case of exception.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Good suggestion with the optional, I included it in my code as `-> str | None`. I wondered about putting the return statement in try: as well, but have read multiple times, that caution is needed when using return in the try/except/else/finally statements.